# Bootstrap Carousel scroll top when slide

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

I have a BS carousel inside a BS modal and the content inside the carousel-items is very long (you have to scroll down). Therefore I want that the page scroll to top if the carousel item changed.

I've already tried different IDs and classes for `scrollTop` but not working.

**CODE**

```
$('#carouselExampleControls').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    $('body').scrollTop(0);
    console.log('slid event');
});
```

**FIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/cdheumann/ajf7vs8m/

```js
$('#carouselExampleControls').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    $("body").scrollTop(0);
    console.log('slid event');
});
```

```css
.modal-dialog {
    max-width: 90vw;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/640/1000/animals" alt="First slide">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/640/1000/animals" alt="Second slide">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/640/1000/animals" alt="Third slide">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `body` here, use `.modal` instead.

```
$('#carouselExampleControls').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    $('.modal').scrollTop(0);
    console.log('slid event');
});
```

Do you want to scroll smoothly? use jQuery `animate` function but don't forget to include `jQuery` not `jQuery slim` ( that you are included ).

```
$('#carouselExampleControls').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    $(".modal").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
    console.log('slid event');
});
```

**Default**

```js
$('#carouselExampleControls').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    $(".modal").scrollTop(0);
    console.log('slid event');
});
```

```css
.modal-dialog {
    max-width: 90vw;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/640/1000/animals" alt="First slide">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/640/1000/animals" alt="Second slide">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/640/1000/animals" alt="Third slide">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Scroll Animation**

```js
$('#carouselExampleControls').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    $(".modal").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
    console.log('slid event');
});
```

```css
.modal-dialog {
    max-width: 90vw;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/640/1000/animals" alt="First slide">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/640/1000/animals" alt="Second slide">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/640/1000/animals" alt="Third slide">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```