# React Bootstrap Carousel scroll top when slide

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, reactstrap, bootstrap-carousel

I'm trying to figure out how to make my **Reactstrap carousel** scroll up when I slide to the next or previous item.

This is exactly how I need it to work [Bootstrap Carousel scroll top when slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61246329/bootstrap-carousel-scroll-top-when-slide)
But I did things in another way using reactstrap node module and I'm not quite getting how to make something like `window.scrollTo(0,0)` relate to the next and previous slide buttons.

Here goes the code:

```
import React, { useState, Component } from 'react';
import fotos2 from '../data/fotos2'

import {
  Carousel,
  CarouselItem,
  CarouselControl,
  CarouselIndicators,
  CarouselCaption
} from 'reactstrap';

const Example = (props) => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(props.id);
  const [animating, setAnimating] = useState(false);

  const scrollTop = () => {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
  };

  const next = () => {
    if (animating) return;
    const nextIndex = activeIndex === fotos2.length - 1 ? 0 : activeIndex + 1 || 
    setActiveIndex(nextIndex);
    scrollTop();
  }

  const previous = () => {
    if (animating) return;
    const nextIndex = activeIndex === 0 ? fotos2.length - 1 : activeIndex - 1;
    setActiveIndex(nextIndex);
    scrollTop();
  }

  const goToIndex = (newIndex) => {
    if (animating) return;
    setActiveIndex(newIndex);
  }

  const slides = fotos2.map((item) => {


    return (
      <CarouselItem data-pause="hover" style={{ minHeight: '20em' }}
        className="custom-tag"
        tag="div"
        key={item.url}
        onExiting={() => setAnimating(true)}
        onExited={() => setAnimating(false)}
      >
        {/* <img src={props.foto} alt={item.altText}/> */}
        <img className="imagenCarousel" src={item.url} alt={item.altText} />

        <CarouselCaption className="text-danger" captionText={item.caption} captionHeader={item.caption} />

      </CarouselItem>


    );
  });

  return (
    <div>

      {/* interval={false} para el slider */}
      <Carousel
        activeIndex={activeIndex}
        next={next}
        previous={previous}
        interval={false}
      >

        <CarouselIndicators items={fotos2} activeIndex={activeIndex} onClickHandler={goToIndex} />
        {slides}
        <CarouselControl direction="prev" directionText="Previous" onClickHandler={previous} />
        <CarouselControl direction="next" directionText="Next" onClickHandler={next} />
      </Carousel>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Example;
```

I already tried a couple solutions but it makes the main window scroll up instead of scrolling only the Modal that contains the carousel

Thank you in advance for your time !

Answer (score 0):

You need to call useEffect everytime make change to the activeIndex to scroll element to top.Try this and let me know if it works..

```
useEffect(()=>{window.scrollTop(0);},[activeIndex])
```

Comment: Hello, I tried using ```useEffect(()=>{window.scrollTo(0,0);},[activeIndex])``` but it makes the main window scroll up when I open the modal that contains the carousel. But it has to be close to this answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) you will see that `scrollTo` either accepts 2 parameters (x,y) or 1 parameter of type object. Your usage of `window.scrollTo(0);` will cause errors because it is not passing an object nor passing 2 parameters.

You can fix this by adding a second parameter for the y-axis:

```
const scrollTop = () => {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
};
```

In addition, your current implementation of scrolling to top right when `next` or `previous` is invoked will scroll the window to the top right away. If you want to retain the behavior on the Stack Overflow question you've linked (i.e., scroll-to-top after animation is done), you can opt to trigger the `scrollTop` function on `onExited` prop callback of `CarouselItem` component

```
<CarouselItem
    onExited={() => {
        setAnimating(false);
        scrollTop();
    }}
></CarouselItem>
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-bird-n2vno?file=/src/App.js

---

The concept and logic is the same for the Modal overflow concerns. This time you can use [Element.scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll) - where Element is a React ref to the modal scrollable DOM element.

```
const containerRef = useRef(null);

const scrollTop = () => {
  // window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  containerRef.current.scroll(0, 0);
};

<div ref={containerRef}>
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-mclaren-sklgp?file=/src/App.js

useRef hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: Hello!, thanks for your answer. It kinda works, the only thing is it scrolls  the main window up instead of the content on the modal itself. But almost there

Comment: @federico_531 The concept is the same. This time you can use [Element.scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll) - where Element is a React ref to the modal scrollable DOM element. I've edited my answer to include this information and an example sand box. Hope this helps, good luck

Comment: Thanks!! it's now scrolling up only the content inside the element. But you know, the style of the content is a long photo without borders and it was working with only one scrollbar but now when the modal that contains the carousel opens up, I get double scroll bar and I have to be messing with both scroll bars to navigate throught the whole content. I fixed it by deleting the overlow: "auto" but scrollTop() stops working !  Any Idea what could it be?

Comment: yes, you probably added another div with overflow properties. my sandbox was merely an example. re-use the modal's overflowing element - this is where you assign the `ref` to

Comment: Any progress? @federico_531

Comment: No, thanks for asking. I left it aside for now because I needed to move on with other parts of the project and I'm also currently applying to get my first dev job so I've working on getting my portfolio ready.